# Find $x,y$ such that $x=4y$ and $1$-$9$ occur in $x$ or $y$ exactly once.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle, problem-solving

> $x$ is a $5$-digits number, while $y$ is $4$-digits number. $x=4y$, and they used up all numbers from 1 to 9. Find $x,y$.

Can someone give me some ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: Well $4 \mid x$ so $4|$ the number formed by the last two digits of $x$.

Comment: @ julien,  yes....

Comment: My idea would be to program a computer to do it for you. There aren't that many 4-digit numbers.

Comment: Write a program and compute all the probablity $N1N2...N9$ and let $x=N1N2N3N4N5$ and $y=N6N7N8N9$ and verify....

Comment: don't know if this helps or not:  $40001y$ is a multiple of $9$,  Therefore $y$ is too.

Comment: out of curiousity, how do you know it exists? Where did you hear the problem?

Comment: I get it from the internet.

Comment: someone give one example ,so it exists...

Comment: More specifically, $y$'s digits must add to $18$ or $27$ (and $x$'s $27$ or $18$).  There aren't many possibilities to examine in the latter case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the $x,y$ pairs a quick bit of code found.

15768 3942

17568 4392

23184 5796

31824 7956

No insight to offer at the moment I'm afraid..

Comment: Interesting to have pairs of anagrams.

Comment: Yes, I thought so, but it really doesn't leap out at me why this should be, especially since the two pairs don't look like they follow similar rules.

Answer (score 1):

$4 \cdot 5796 = 23184$.

Lucky guess, I guess.

Comment: I can say that my strategy was to throw the large odd numbers into $y$, since their multiple by $4$ will be 'smaller' numbers. I doubt there is really a good explanation for this though